# calling C++ from C# cross platform

Tags: c#, c++, .net, mono

Hi I'm looking for an example of how to call a simple C++ function or class from C# that works cross platform i.e. visual studios and mono, most of the stuff i've found on the web seem to only work via visual studios.

Comment: You can't call a c++ class in c# by the way.

Comment: I didn't know that, thats a bummer..

Comment: Nobody can call a class. That just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @pyCthon: You can't **instanciate** a C++ class in C#, as DeadMG pointed. Anyway *calling a class* doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SWIG for calling C++ code from C#. It seems to work equally well with mono see http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't call C++ functions, because of the name mangling, but you can call `extern "C"` functions via P/Invoke.

This might be a good read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42b9ea93.aspx

Google would of course be valuable too.

I'd say it's unlikely that you will be able to write completely cross-platform P/Invoke code, since so many things are different across platforms.